# How much of C++ is supported in Objective-C++

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, boost, objective-c++

I want to make an iPhone app, but I am planning to make the framework in C++. Is it possible to use things like templates in Objective-C++. I guess really the question is, can I use boost?

Comment: This may not be so helpful as an answer but if you already know C++, picking up Objective-C should be a breeze. Unless of course you're porting an app then I understand the question more.

Comment: It can make sense to use C++ when you need very high performance, like in a game engine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of C++ is supported in Objective C++. It should be possible to use boost, but you might have to port some of the platform dependant things.

Comment: I've used boost without any alterations. It worked right out of the box.

Comment: The main boost libraries should work but some of the IO related libraries probably won't work out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

> Is it possible to use things like templates in Objective-C++.

Yes, but you need to take care how you mix types and interfaces between the pure C++ layers and the Objective-C++ code.  Keep in mind the boundaries between layers, where you would need to convert types such as `std::string` to `NSString`, and so on.

For example, you could implement the core game engine in pure C++, and just implement your controllers and GUI code in Objective-C++.  Then the Obj-C++ code is the glue between the pure C++ engine and Cocoa.

> I guess really the question is, can I use boost?

Given the iPhone OS is a subset of OS X that still provides a full POSIX layer, most Boost libraries *should* work just fine.  It should be just like writing Darwin code.

There are a number of limitations in Objective-C++ to be aware of (taken directly from the [Objective-C 2.0 Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1)):

- you cannot use Objective-C syntax to call a C++ object
- you cannot add constructors or destructors to an Objective-C object
- you cannot use the keywords this and self interchangeably
- the class hierarchies are separate; a C++ class cannot inherit from an Objective-C class, and an Objective-C class cannot inherit from a C++ class
- an exception thrown in Objective-C code cannot be caught in C++ code and, conversely, an exception thrown in C++ code cannot be caught in Objective-C code.

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer, the least you can do is state why.  The accepted answer (currenly with 9 votes) rather over-simplistically states that all features of C++ are available.  This answer says a qualified yes, and quotes directly from the language reference explaining the limitations, and it gets downvoted. How does that work?

Comment: Limitation #2 heard like general C++ method can be added to Objective-C class. But it's hard to believe adding C++ method to Objective-C class is possible. Can you explain more about this? Because the link is broken I can't check it more.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find an equivalent document to replace the above. I've send a note to the ADC documentation team requesting it be restored.  Point #2 simply means that an ObjC class in a `.mm` module still has the same `init` and `dealloc` methods for lifecycle management; you simply can't mix ObjC and C++ approaches within the same class.  You can't add a C++ method to and ObjC class, but you can call between the two within a .`mm`. I hope this clarifies the above.

Answer (score 4):

It should be pointed out that you can't just do everything that you can do in C++ in Objective-C++.  For example you can't call virtual functions on C++ objects from an Objective-C class.  Once you call into a C/C++ function you can do whatever you want though.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. You can call C++ virtual methods from within Objective-C++ code.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yfrxwg9

States that:
"Objective-C++ similarly strives to allow C++ class instances to serve as instance variables. This is possible as long as the C++ class in question (along with all of its superclasses) does not have any virtual member functions defined. If any virtual member functions are present, the C++ class may not serve as an Objective-C instance variable."

It appears in newer versions of the OS that this isn't a problem, but I think it is on the iPHONE OS.

Answer (score 3):

Objective C++ is a superset of C++. Everything that you can do in C/C++ can be done in Obj-C++. The "Objective" portion contains, among other things, a Smalltalk-esque messaging system and other additions to C++.

Answer (score 2):

C++ objects in Objective C will NOT necessarily act like in C++. For example constructors and destructors are not automatically called and (i think) that you can't implement virtual methods...

Answer (score 1):

Boost is useful but it is also a large overhead to add to a project.

Make sure you really need it before you go adding it.

For Regex support: [RegexLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/).

For everything else: **Cocoa**.